# Django restframework permissions

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, permissions, django-rest-framework

it is a basic api, I have 3 kinds of users -> admin, companies, employees.

admin can view, edit and delete all of them, companies can view and delete it's employees and employees can only see the videos updated by his company.

So each companie will have an admin panel that they can upload training videos and register it's employees, so each company has it's own panel, they don't see other companies.

Do I need to create a custom user model to do that? How would I create that model, How can I set those permissions?

How can I manage the register form, login, urls that the companies and employees can or can't access

**my models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    empresa_nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    razao_social = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=18, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.empresa_nome


class Employee(models.Model):
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='employees')
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone


class Test(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='treinamentos')
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoria


class Video(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='video')
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ordem = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    pergunta = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    certo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    errado = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoria
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Company, Employee, Test, Video

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff')


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        exclude = []


class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        exclude = []


class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    video = VideoSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('id', 'categoria', 'video', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
        exclude = []


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employees = EmployeeSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    treinamentos = TestSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    #user_obj = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'empresa_nome', 'razao_social', 'cnpj', 'employees', 'treinamentos')
        exclude = []
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers, viewsets
from restcompanies.views import UserViewSet, CompanyViewSet, EmployeeViewSet, TestViewSet, VideoViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'companies', CompanyViewSet)
router.register(r'employees', EmployeeViewSet)
router.register(r'tests', TestViewSet)
router.register(r'videos', VideoViewSet)

app_name = 'restcompanies'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='restcompanies')),
]
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: @arjun27 I've updated the question with some code

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the view by checking the permissions in the template and branching the rendering based on permissions. For example, you could set a "can_edit" flag and pass that back in the context. Then in your template do:

```
{% if can_edit %}
*edit only code goes here
{% endif %}
```

Alternately, you can provide different templates for the same view based on role and company. This can be accomplished by using a TemplateView and overriding get_template_names e.g.

```
class AdminView(TemplateView):


def get_template_names(self):
    if empresa_nome == 'company1':
        return 'company1template.html'
```

But in my opinion the latter solution is only good if the templates are quite different whereas if it's simply enabling/disabling options in similar templates, then the first solution is better.

You don't necessarily need a custom user model since you can make lots of various roles in django by default and assign these to users. For example, in one project I check permissions using user roles:

```
def checkPermissions(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return None
    if request.user.groups.filter(name='MerchantSuperAdmin').exists() or request.user.is_superuser:
        return 'SU' #can access whatever
    if request.user.groups.count() == 1 and request.user.groups.filter(name='employee').exists():
        return 'readonly'
```

In this case I have a custom user role called MerchantSuperAdmin and another called Employee and I assign these to various users.

... etc. Then in the template you can have select html of javascript based on context['permission'] or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In django permission are model/class based, not instance/object based. If you want them to be object based you will have to write your own permission models OR (and I would suggest this) use one of the existing packages that do just this. A package I like is django-guardian ( https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ ), it has very good documentation and is quite easy to use. Moreover, since you are using django rest framework there is a good chance it is installed already since django rest lists it as one of the optional packages under its installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to relate users to companies and apply permission logic on that, yes, probably using a custom user model is the best option. You can read about how to do that [in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Django Rest Framework lets you to allow/forbid access to a view depending on arbitrary criteria, including the resource being requested. See the [documentation section about custom permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions).

Answer (score 0):

I would use custom permissions with inheritance.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

```
class IsAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return do_some_custom_checking(...)

class IsCompany(IsAdmin):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return do_some_custom_checking(...) or super(IsCompany, self).has_permission(request, view)

class IsEmployee(IsCompany):
    def has_permission(self, request view):
        return do_some_custom_checking(....) or super(IsEmployee, self).has_permission(request, view)
```